# What is the most efficient method to parse this line of text?

Tags: regex, parsing, python-2.7

The following is a row that I have extracted from the web:

> AIG $30 AIG is an international renowned insurance company listed on the NYSE. A period is required. Manual Auto Active 3 0.0510, 0.0500, 0.0300 [EXTRACT]

I will like to create 5 separate variables by parsing the text and retrieving the relevant data. However, i seriously don't understand the REGEX documentation! Can anyone guide me on how i can do it correctly with this example?

> > Name = AIG
> >
> > CurrentPrice = $30
> >
> > Status = Active
> >
> > World_Ranking = 3
> >
> > History = 0.0510, 0.0500, 0.0300

Comment: The key to regexes is that you have to be able to describe the rules for finding things yourself, in English.  You can't just give examples.  You have to think in terms of "the name is the first string of characters up to the first blank" and "the history is a set of three decimal numbers separated by commas." So write those out and put them in the body of your quesiton.  How is the computer to find World_Ranking? How does it know what the status is?  Describe those in English and then it's a matter of writing the regex, which we can help you with.  Defining the rules is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you want to achieve here. There's no need to use regexps, you could just use `str.split`:

```
>>> str = "AIG $30 AIG is an international renowned insurance company listed on the NYSE. A period is required. Manual Auto Active 3 0.0510, 0.0500, 0.0300 [EXTRACT]"
>>> list = str.split()
>>> dict = { "Name": list[0], "CurrentPrice": list[1], "Status": list[19], "WorldRanking": list[20], "History": ' '.join((list[21], list[22], list[23])) }

#output
>>> dict
{'Status': 'Active', 'CurrentPrice': '$30', 'Name': 'AIG', 'WorldRanking': '3', 'History': '0.0510, 0.0500, 0.0300'}
```

Instead of using `list[19]` and so on, you may want to change it to `list[-n]` to not depend to the company's description length. Like that:

```
>>> history = ' '.join(list[-4:-1])
>>> history
'0.0510, 0.0500, 0.0300'
```

For floating history indexes it could be easier to use `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> history = re.findall("\d\.\d{4}", str)
>>> ['0.0510', '0.0500', '0.0300']
```

For identifying status, you could get the indexes of history values and then substract by one:

```
>>> [ i for i, substr in enumerate(list) if re.match("\d\.\d{4}", substr) ]
[21, 22, 23]

>>> list[21:24]
['0.0510,', '0.0500,', '0.0300,']

>>> status = list[20]
>>> status
'3'
```

Comment: Hi IOXenus, That seems to work for this sentence. But, if I need to do it repetitively for multiple rows, i wonder if it will work. Let me give it a try. brb!

Comment: Just curious, what if the historical prices could have more than 3 elements? How may I capture all?

Comment: @TingPing sure, but make certain you use negative list indexes for the end of string, since the word count of company's description may vary. So you use `list[n]` for Name and CurrentPrice, but `list[-n]` for other variables like Status and History.

Comment: One way to do so is to figure out the negative index position for the variable Rank and run a loop to zero. For example, if the reversed index position for Rank is -5, i would start a loop to join -4,-3,-2 and -1 to get the data. Is there a more efficient method because I heard for loop can be very slow for huge data source.

Comment: The re method may not be robust. If the current price is $0.30, it would also return it as part of the result.

Comment: @TingPing It wouldn't, if the price doesn't have four digits after the point (like $0.3000). Also, you could iterate over the slice of list which exludes price, like `list[3:]`